# Why does my vb.net http cookie fail to write in IE (only, works fine i FireFox)

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, cookies, save

My vb.net code writes a cookie value and later retrieves it.

The code that writes the cookie is:

```
Dim cookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("mySessionID", mySessionID)
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90)
cookie.HttpOnly = True
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
```

And the code to read it on a subsequent page:

```
Dim myRetrivedSessionID as String = Request.Cookies("mySessionID").Value
```

When the code is run **in FireFox it runs fine**, but **when run in IE8** ( or IE7 ) the "Request.Cookies("mySessionID").Value" always throws the exception ***"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."***, which I interpreted to mean it could not find the saved value to load?

Any idea why this i failing?
More importantly, how do I fix it!

Thanks for your help, I've been beating my head against this issue for days now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue causing my problem.

Turns out that the combination of IIS, IE and a server name containing an underscore '_' in its name causes some sort of problem keeps cookies from working correctly.

I finally stubbled upon this refrence to the issue : [Thread: missing sessionid with iis 64 bit isapi_redirect.dll jboss and MSIE](http://forums.iis.net/p/1147938/1879164.aspx)

In is it said:

> The problem in our case was an underscore in the URL. It is not accepted by IE7 but by all other browser if a part of the servername has an underscore. (server_1 is nok, server-1 is ok)
>
> rgrds

When I tested on a server without the underscore in it name, on the same browser, the everything worked fine.